# People's preferences assigning them to a group using Excel

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

I would love some assistance with the following problem.

Each year for school camps we take the students preferences 1-6 of who they'd like to bunk in with for the week. We usually sort this out manually, but there has to be a much quicker way to do it using Excel.
(Is this a marriage problem?- I just read about it on this site)

+Each student should have at least one preference
+The problem is that some students aren't chosen by anyone else, but they must still be placed with another student of their choosing.
+There are rooms for 4, 6 and 8 students to a room.
+Although the image shows 26 possibilities of the preferences as given by students, there are actually 104 students.

[image: sample_sheet_of_the_preferences_once_selected_by_the_students]

Using mathematics and excel are a personal interest of mine, but i am in the beginning stages of my skills so please explain your thoughts in layman's terms.

If anyone can give an example of how to do it in Excel I'd be so grateful.

Cheers

Comment: This also depends on what you want to optimize: Maximize the number of rank-1 pairings? Minimize the number of rank-6 (or even unranked) pairings? Avoid extreme ranking differences between rooms? I can imagine that one would even try to *avoid* following maximal preferences as that could lead to the six worst bullies in one room etc.

Comment: Haha. Maybe the 6 bullies in one room would be a pleasant trip for the rest of the students! As long as the students get at least one preference, maybe more.

Comment: Just an observation: the problem is not always solvable.  E.g. there are 60 students $\{1,2,...,60\}$ and each of 1-6 prefers someone from 7-12, and each of 7-12 prefers someone from 13-18, etc., and finally each of 55-60 prefers someone from 1-6.  So start with 1, who must room with someone from 7-12, who must room with someone from 13-18, etc, and you'd need a room of size 10, which you don't have.

Comment: Did a brute-force implementation. With all cabin sizes $= 8$ and number of students $N \le 48$ it usually finds a solution within minutes. But sometimes it doesn't stop for hours and I have to manually stop the algorithm. A more sophisticated method (if such exists) is clearly needed for $N=104$ and/or for smaller cabin sizes.